# Unable to compute hash of

Tags: android-studio, gradle

When I use `minifyEnabled true shrinkResources true` gradle task failed with an exception 
`Execution failed for task ':xxxx:packageRelease'.

> Unable to compute hash of D:\asspace\xxxx\xxxx\build\intermediates\classes-proguard\release\classes.jar
>   `

Comment: Could you run with --info option to get more log output ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show full console logs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'. > Unable to compute hash of /../AndroidStudioProjects/../classes.jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31643339/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apppackagerelease-unable-to-compute-hash)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please, read warnings in console carefully. I`ve also faced with similar issue and in my case there were warnings about processing one of third party libraries. After applying corresponding changes related with the library to proguard file, all started to work correctly

Answer (score 6):

This fixed the problem for me:
add those to the Proguard:

```
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.
```

Comment: Almost the same，some classes can not be proguarded.I have checked my libs and added rules in my proguard file.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue. For me, my project's proguard file, namely, `proguard-rules.pro`,  was somehow renamed to `proguard-android.txt`.

The `proguard-android.txt` is reserved for Android's default proguard rules, so essentially, I was overriding Android's proguard file, which was causing havoc, and I would get the *Unable to compute hash* message.

Once I changed the filename in my project from `proguard-android.txt` to `proguard-rules.pro` I was able to get things working.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Anyone found a solution to this issue?