# how to remove unused code from android-support-v4.jar

Tags: android, jar

I import [iosched](https://github.com/google/iosched) into my android-studio,and to learn how to remove unused code from jars.When I executing 'installDebug' there is no problem,but when I executing 'installQualityassurance', or just changed minifyEnabled's vaule to true and then executing 'installDebug' again,there will be a problem like below:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':android:packageDebug'.

  > Unable to compute hash of E:\Android\android_studio_workspace\iosched\android\build\intermediates\classes-proguard\debug\classes.jar

I know the key point to remove unused code from jar is change minifyEnabled's vaule to true,but in my project ,for some jars it works,but for android-support-v4.jar has no effect. What should I do to remove unused code in android-support-v4.jar?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31643339/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apppackagerelease-unable-to-compute-hash

Comment: Use proGuard instead of removing code from android-support-v4.jar

Comment: @sasikumar thank you,I will try it follow the answer.

Comment: @Attaullah the build.gradle is [build.gradle](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/build.gradle/)