# Generate Signed APK: Errors while building APK Android Studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, proguard

I am unable to generate Signed APK using `minifyEnabled true` and `shrinkResources true`

App Level : build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "......."
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    configurations {
        compile.exclude group: "org.apache.httpcomponents", module: "httpclient"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev149-1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-gson:1.20.0'
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.2'
}
```

**MessageView**

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleRelease]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkReleaseManifest
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGithubClansFab162Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareReleaseDependencies
:app:compileReleaseAidl
:app:compileReleaseRenderscript
:app:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:app:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeReleaseAssets
:app:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseResources
:app:mergeReleaseResources
:app:processReleaseManifest
:app:processReleaseResources
:app:generateReleaseSources
:app:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: .....YouTubeRecyclerViewFragment.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: ....GetPlaylistAsyncTask.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
:app:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseSources
:app:proguardRelease UP-TO-DATE
:app:dexRelease
:app:shrinkReleaseResources
Removed unused resources: Binary resource data reduced from 741KB to 402KB: Removed 45%
Note: If necessary, you can disable resource shrinking by adding
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources false
        }
    }
}
:app:validateExternalOverrideSigning
:app:packageRelease FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
> Unable to compute hash of ....\app\build\intermediates\classes-proguard\release\classes.jar
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 7.45 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: Can you edit your answer with the source codes in `YouTubeRecyclerViewFregment` ? Seems you are using some deprecated APIs

Answer (score 13):

**You are getting**

```
Removed unused resources: Binary resource data reduced from 741KB to 402KB: Removed 45%
Note: If necessary, you can disable resource shrinking by adding
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources false
        }
    }
}
:app:validateExternalOverrideSigning
:app:packageRelease FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
```

**Resource shrinking** works only in conjunction with code shrinking.

**minifyEnabled** is an Android tool that will decrease the size of your application when you go to build it .

```
android {

    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true // This must be first 
            minifyEnabled true   // This must be after shrinkResources 
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

> If you haven't already built your app using minifyEnabled for code
>   shrinking, then try that before enabling shrinkResources, because you
>   might need to edit your proguard-rules.pro file to keep classes or
>   methods that are created or invoked dynamically before you start
>   removing resources.

Please read official Guideline about **[Shrink Your Code and Resources](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html)**

**Advice**

Use latest version

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'
targetSdkVersion 25
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0' // set other 25.1.0
```

**NOTE**

```
YouTubeRecyclerViewFragment.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
```

***Use Alternate Latest Version .***

Comment: This answered in 2017, but it helps me a lot in 2023! Wow

Comment: @钟智强 left this field. It's really nice to see the comments.

Answer (score 4):

Clean project and start again generate signed Build/Apk.
its working fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

First check whether you really need to use **shrinkResources**

If so, do as suggested in developers link **https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html#shrink-resources** mentioned above by **IntelliJ Amiya**, you have to use like below

```
android {

    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true  // -- always add this above minifyEnabled --
            minifyEnabled true   
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to generate signed APK using terminal by gradle command see your stack trace that will give you detailed log where has the problem.

> In Windows

`$gradle clean`

```
$  gradle --stacktrace assembleRelease
```

> In Ubuntu

`$./gradlew clean`

```
$./gradlew --stacktrace assembleRelease
```

if you have still problem  post you stack trace here

Answer (score 0):

This `:app:proguardRelease UP-TO-DATE` .. makes this log not complete enough to say if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34714083/4271923) will help or not.

Please do clean + build release again to have full log with all steps, you may want also to add `--info` to gradle options, or even `--debug` to get more diagnostic messages in gradle build log.

Clean+build may also fix some weird problem of gradle/other-tool not correctly updating some file and reusing older incorrect one - rarely happens.

Also try to switch minification OFF (not solution, just experiment), whether it helps (to localize the problem *is* really with proguard minification and not elsewhere).

And of course if there are proguard related errors during minification, try to follow advice from the linked answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot sign the apk in Android Studio, manually signed it with

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore my_application.apk alias_name
```

if you not have the key, generated it with `keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000`

You also can manually signed as the [manual](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#signing-manually) do:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.jks-keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias app
zipalign -v -p 4 my-app-unaligned.apk my-app.apk
apksigner sign --ks my-release-key.jks my-app.apk
```

check the signed apk

```
apksigner verify my-app.apk
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Keytool binary or exe to generate a private keystore. Instructions in below link. You can then sign your app using this keystore. Keytool gets installed when you install Java.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-3503/ggfen/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one of your libraries (especially libraries which can use networking(`httpClient`, `okHttp` etc)) conflicts.. Try adding all of your libraries to a new project(do not add any code or component to your project).. If error occurs in that project too so the problem is in one of the libraries.. Try to uncomment libraries one by one..