# Gradle Build failed with ProGuard enabled, missing classes.jar

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, android-proguard

I'm getting the following error when trying to build a signed APK with ProGuard enabled:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
>   Unable to compute hash of D:\Work\Android\MyApp\app\build\intermediates\classes-proguard\release\classes.jar

I checked the path given, and there is no classes.jar file. Where can I get the .jar from?

Comment: check there is somewhere error in code or something missed or add here full error log.

Comment: That's the only error.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31643339/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apppackagerelease-unable-to-compute-hash) question or just add

```
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.**
```

to your proguard rules.

Comment: I actually saw that post and have those rules in my file.Adding the line you posted doesn't help.

Comment: Can you please explain why **android.gms** is important to OP's question specifically?

Answer (score 0):

Add these to your `proguard-project.txt` If you are using support libraries.

```
-dontwarn android.support.v7.**
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }
```

<sub>Credits to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31173974/1841194).</sub>