# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease' while generating APK

Tags: android, proguard, mpandroidchart, android-proguard

I have generated an APK of my Android application (as a try) and I did not have any problem, the APK has been generated correctly.

Now, I want to obfuscate my code while generating the APK so I used the following line on my `release` block on `build.gradle` file.

```
minifyEnabled true
```

The problem is that now it throws me the following error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
>   java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.

with a lot of warnings. To be more exact, 1018 warnings.

Most of them are like:

> Warning:com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7: can't find referenced class org.spongycastle.asn1.tsp.MessageImprint

or

> Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmBaseDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.Sort

Always is the same error. A class that cannot find a referenced class.

I am using **[`MPAndroidChart`](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)** so I think it is something related (because of the name of the packages that appears on the warnings) but I am not able to correct those warnings.

**EDIT:** As a prove, I have tried keeping the classes using:

```
-keep public class com.itextpdf.text.pdf.**
```

on my `proguard-rules.pro` file but I still have the same warnings.

My `release` section on `build.gradle` file is:

```
release {
    minifyEnabled true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
```

Am I missing something while obfuscating my code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33589318/error-building-apk-when-minifyenabled-true)

Comment: @VygintasB I do not think `-dontwarn` will be a safe option. I am trying using `-keep` the public classes but I am not able to make it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I have found that `MPAndroidChart` has a **[document](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Proguard)** in which tells you how to configure Proguard.

With the following configuration:

```
-keep class com.github.mikephil.charting.** { *; }
-dontwarn io.realm.**
```

I was able to create the obfuscate APK without any warnings.

Also, I have noticed that `itextpdf` was a library that I used on the past but I did not need it nowadays so I just have to delete it from the dependencies on my gradle file and the warnings also have dissapeared.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for this issue during apk generation.

Open `build.gradle(app)` and change build type as following.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
    }
}
```