# How to enable ProGuard obfuscation in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have to protect my app by enabling Proguard obfuscation in Android Studio. I have searched for the process of how to apply it but i did not get any clear solution. When i try it, i always get an error. So can anyone tell me the clear steps to apply it in my app?

I am doing this by the following steps:

1. In Android Studio, open up an Android project.
2. Change to Project View.
3. Change the following line:

   `minifyEnable false` to `minifyEnable true`
4. Set ProGuard Rules(optional)

   4.1 In Project View, select the proguard-rules.pro file.

   4.2 Add in the following lines to tell ProGuard not to obfuscate certain classes.

   ```
   -keepclassmembers class com.dom925.xxxx 
   {
     public *
   }
   ```

**Error that I am getting by following the steps are**

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
>   Unable to compute hash of D:\Android\Pojectname\app\build\intermediates\classes-proguard\release\classes.jar

Comment: post your build.gradle so we can make an more accurate answer based on your dependencies

Comment: here is some reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30934729/cant-generate-signed-apk-from-android-studio-execution-failed-for-task-packa

Comment: here is some reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20885725/how-to-use-the-proguard-in-android-studio

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I figured out the problem:

Open up the proguard-rules.pro for your project and add this to the bottom:

```
-dontwarn java.nio.file.Files
-dontwarn java.nio.file.Path
-dontwarn java.nio.file.OpenOption
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
```

Basically how I solved it was this I tried to run my app in 'release' mode and got a bunch of errors similar to this guy here: https://github.com/square/okio/issues/144

I pretty much followed what he said and fixed it.

Hope this can help others with generating their APK's!

visit more detail here :

[Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'. > Unable to compute hash of /../AndroidStudioProjects/../classes.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31643339/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apppackagerelease-unable-to-compute-hash)

Comment: but still i got error friend  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35150026/how-to-generate-proguard-obfuscation-in-using-android-studio

Answer (score 58):

To enable ProGuard in Android Studio.

Below is the sample how to enable default ProGuard in Android Studio.

1. Go to the build.gradle file of app
2. enable the **minifyEnabled true**
3. enable  **shrinkResources true** to reduce the APK size
4. `proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')`
   to enable the default one. If you want to use your own proguard file then use the below rules.

   ```
   buildTypes {
       release {
           debuggable false
           minifyEnabled true
           shrinkResources true
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }

       debug {
           debuggable true
           minifyEnabled true
           shrinkResources true
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
   }
   ```

The link with ProGuard settings for Android and other settings are available in these links:

- [Default ProGuard file](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html)
- [Gist with example](https://gist.github.com/maheshwarLigade/7143ae567fe8ac7c1e20)

For more detail go through [this link](https://techwasti.com/enabling-proguard-for-android/)

Comment: why do we need to obfuscate for debug?

Comment: good question!! but this is an available option if you want to use based on the use case you can or just ignore.

Answer (score 1):

if you are building the android project with jack, then it will automatically do the shrinking, obfuscation, repackaging and multidex.
Just add below in :

```
defaultConfig {
       jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }        
    }
```

and in build types, mention the project `proguard` file :

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            // Jack build environment does not require minifyEnabled or shrinkResources.
            // Conceptually, the jack compiler consolidates the functionality of javac, ProGuard, and dex in a single conversion step
            //minifyEnabled = true      
            //shrinkResources true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
       }

       debug {
...................
        }
    }
```

To disable the ProGuard obfuscation, it is required to add below line in your proguard-project.txt file

```
####No obfuscation
-dontobfuscate
```