# How to generate ProGuard obfuscation in using Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have to protect my app by enabling Pro guard obfuscation in Android studio. I have searched for the process of how to apply it but i did not get any clear solution. When i try it, i always get an error.So can anyone give me solution.

Error logs:-

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleRelease]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkReleaseManifest
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareReleaseDependencies
:app:compileReleaseAidl
:app:compileReleaseRenderscript
:app:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:app:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeReleaseAssets
:app:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseResources
:app:mergeReleaseResources
:app:processReleaseManifest
:app:processReleaseResources
:app:generateReleaseSources
:app:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac

Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

 :app:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
 :app:compileReleaseSources
 :app:proguardRelease
 Exception while processing task 
 java.io.IOException: Can't read [D:\Android\Package_name\app\bin\classes]    (No      such file or directory)
 at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:188)
 at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:158)
 at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:136)
 at proguard.InputReader.execute(InputReader.java:66)
 at proguard.ProGuard.readInput(ProGuard.java:218)
 at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:82)
 at proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask.proguard(ProGuardTask.java:1074)
          atcom.android.build.gradle.tasks.AndroidProGuardTask.doMinification(AndroidProGuardTask.java:139)
  atcom.android.build.gradle.tasks.AndroidProGuardTask$1.run(AndroidProGuardTask.java:115)
at com.android.builder.tasks.Job.runTask(Job.java:48)
at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.SimpleWorkQueue$EmptyThreadContext.runTask(SimpleWorkQueue.java:41)
at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:227)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Error:java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
at proguard.io.DirectoryPump.pumpDataEntries(DirectoryPump.java:50)
at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:184)
... 12 more
:app:dexRelease
:app:validateExternalOverrideSigning
:app:packageRelease FAILED
 Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
```

> Unable to compute hash of      D:\Android\Package_name\app\build\intermediates\classes-proguard\release\classes.jar
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:Total time: 9.667 secs
>   Information:2 errors
>   Information:0 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console

build gradle:-

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "package_name"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.1"
}

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
buildTypes {
    release
            {
                minifyEnabled true
                proguardFile 'D:/Android/Packagename/app/proguard-rules.pro'
            }
    debug
            {
                debuggable true
                minifyEnabled true
                proguardFile 'D:/Android/Packagename/app/proguard-rules.pro'
                applicationIdSuffix ".debug"

            }
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
  }
  }

  dependencies {
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
  }
```

proguard-rules.pro:-

```
-injars      bin/classes
-injars      libs
-injars      com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0
-injars      com.android.support:design:23.1.1
-libraryjars /usr/local/java/android-sdk/platforms/android-22/android.jar

-dontpreverify
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
 public <init>(android.content.Context);
 public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
 public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
 public void set*(...);
 }

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
 public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
 }

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
 public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
 }

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
 static android.os.Parcelable$Creator CREATOR;
 }

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
 public static <fields>;
 }

 -dontwarn android.support.**
 -dontwarn com.github.**
 -dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**
 -dontwarn com.etsy.android.grid.**
 -dontwarn java.nio.file.Files
 -dontwarn java.nio.file.Path
 -dontwarn java.nio.file.OpenOption
 -dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
```

Comment: what is your project path

Comment: where i was declare friend ?

Comment: means where is your project in your hdd try replacing proguardFile 'D:/Android/Packagename/app/proguard-rules.pro' with proguardFile 'proguard-rules.pro'

Comment: Yeah ! thanks now i replace      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

Comment: Hmmm, i 'm accept still i will got error friend.. Anybody give me solution

Comment: what is the error now

Comment: Same error log i mention top the question

Comment: java.io.IOException: Can't read  [D:\Android\Package_name\app\bin\classes]    (Nosuch file or directory)

Comment: try clean the project and rebuilding the project and then try the proguard release export

Comment: did you generate Pro guard in android studio ?

Comment: Yeah thanks i try & rebuild my application 10 time still i got this two error

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
> Unable to compute hash of D:\Android\Phone_Backup\app\build\intermediates\classes-proguard\release\classes.jar

Comment: java.io.IOException: Can't read [D:\Android\Phone_Backup\app\bin\classes] (No such file or directory)

Comment: proguard is unable to find classes under D:\Android\Package_name\app\bin\classes , make sure your application id matches the package name

Comment: build/outputs/mapping/release/mapping.txt  i miss this file mapping.txt

Comment: how to include this file mapping..

Comment: it is automatically generated by proguard u dont have to include it

Comment: -printmapping build/outputs/mapping/release/mapping.txt  .....

Comment: its working thanks friend..

Comment: please upvote the answer also, if u can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try replacing

```
proguardFile 'D:/Android/Packagename/app/proguard-rules.pro'
```

with:

```
proguardFile 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

Comment: Add the proguard.txt below -printmappingbuild/outputs/mapping/release/mapping.txt